# Cassandra driver not exposing metrics

Tags: cassandra, jmx

I created a cassandra cluster and session.

```
  val newSession = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost")
            .build().newSession()
    newSession.execute("SELECT * from workout.competitorsentity")
    return newSession
```

However when I go to the jconsole for this jvm I don't see the cassandra jvm metrics. 
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't see Cassandra metrics in driver - driver exposes only its own metrics, and they are under the `cluster1-metrics` part of the tree (see [driver documentation about metrics](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/metrics/) for more details).

If you need to see Cassandra metrics, you need to connect JConsole to Cassandra process(-es) itself (by default they are available only on `localhost` interface, so you may need to expose them outside if you're connecting from another machine).

Comment: I want to see the driver metrics

Comment: have you checked under the `cluster1-metrics` tree? Works just fine for me without anything special: https://photos.app.goo.gl/xvxHLGN9PptrDQNV6